# composer.json cannot created, to run heroku

Tags: php, heroku

I have Heroku login in my device, and try to deploy a folder of php codes in Heroku.
However when I tried to create composer.json, it got error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwRJH.png)

what should I do?

Comment: If this is a work computer, you ask IT. If it's your personal computer, you're running as an account that doesn't have permission to access `D:\xampp\htdocs\kuiz`. Perhaps you used a different username to install XAMPP?

Comment: Looking at the error message, it seems like the issue is on your local system and not on Heroku?